# Is there a way to require a signature or authorization when POSTing JSON data to a Django database with Python?

Tags: python, json, django

Say I have a Django database in an API storing a bunch of JSON data. I have a scraper webscraping a site and posting the info at specific endpoints. It runs swimmingly but, if I were to share my API, I worry that there may be a malicious actor or some troll that might want to POST fraudulent data to the database. So the question is, is there a key or or some functionality that authorizes the poster to upload to the database? How would I implement this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you don't want to roll it by hand, then e.g. with https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Hmm... I suppose I could. I spent the day skimming through this but just to be clear, is it possible to create a simple static token that is available for any script to get clearance to upload? The examples I keep hitting are all giving each user their own token for authorization. I don't want to authorize any user specifically.

Comment: Well yes, there is - an if statement in your "post data" view that returns a "not authorized" response.